# Please guide: I want to use payload variable created in excelutility class to another java executable class

Tags: java, excel, automation, frameworks, apache-poi

Trying to use payload variable extracted from an excel sheet in another executable class where I want to post the payload on MQ, although not able to access the variable. How can I use this variable to other class.

```
  package datasource;
 
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class excelUtility {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
            String excelfilePath= "src/main/resources/Book1.xlsx";
    
            FileInputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(excelfilePath);
    
            XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            XSSFSheet sheet= workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
    
            int rows= sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int cols= sheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum();
    
            for (int r=0; r<=rows; r++){
    
                XSSFRow row= sheet.getRow(r);
    
                for(int c=0; c<cols; c++){
    
                    XSSFCell cell= row.getCell(1);
                    String payload= cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(payload);
                   
    
                }
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "in another class"? How are the two classes related? Is the other class executable or do you need to instantiate it inside the current one? Ore vice-versa? Please [edit] your question to add some much needed clarification about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Hi, another class is an executable class where I want to post the payload on MQ.